# Alternative to the linear scale in d3.js to preserve node-specific changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a fairly simple d3 visualisation with 10 nodes on the screen, and a slider that enables you to choose the year to pull the data from (i.e. 2000, 2001 .... 2010) which then updates the value/size of each of the 10 nodes to match the year.

The biggest node from all 10 has a peak value of 14,000 in the year 2000, to a lowest value of 6,000 in the year 2010.

The smallest node from all 10 has a peak value of 1,000 in the year 2000, to a lowest value of 150 in the year 2010.

My problem is that even though the smallest node shrinks by almost a factor of 10 between 2000 and 2010 - you see very little change in its size on the screen because the biggest node (which changes from 14,000 to 6,000) takes up most of the linear scale range.

My requirement is simple enough - for each of the 10 nodes, if the value doubles, then so should the area of the node.  But I'm starting to worry that I need node-specific d3 scales to achieve this?  If not, perhaps there's a different type of scale (logarithmic?) that could help?

Here's the current simple scale I'm using...

```
var circleRadiusScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([150, 14000])
        .range([40, 200]);
```

Thanks a lot for any thoughts!

Comment: could you post what you have done to something like https://jsfiddle.net/ ??

Comment: You could also try some of the scales an see if one fits your needs : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales

Comment: It sounds like you want to chart the change and not the actual value. E.g. set 2000 to 100% and then show how it changed over the years.

Comment: thanks both - Lars - exactly, I want the circles to represent the rate of decay in the numbers - but I thought that was what I was doing already by setting the upper bound of the domain to 14000 (which represents the "100%").  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious!